# Convert Dictionary to List

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list here generated from a long query which the data is used to pump to a report.

```
var result =  
  from..
  where..
  select new  { sale.Id, Username  = u.Name, Amount = p.amount};
output  = result.Tolist();
```

However, i would like to get rid of that long query by creating my own list of value instead. So i create a dictionary to store the key and value. 
My purpose is to convert a dictionary back to a list which has the same output like the query above so that it can be pumped to my report

```
 public static object GetSalesDataBySaleOrderID(SaleOrder sale)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < sale.saleOrderItem.Count(); i++)
        {             
            Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
               {sale.Id.ToString(), sale.Id},                
               {"UserName", sale.User.GetSingleUserById(sale.saleOrderItem[i].UserId).Name},
               {"Amount", sale.saleOrderItem[i].Amount},                   
            };

            list.Add(result);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

I got an error at `list.Add(result);`

> Error  5   Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair'

**---EDIT------------**
I have changed to `List<Dictionary<string, object>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();`   and it solved my error.

However i am still getting the value in dictionary format
[image]

This should be the intended output format in List
[image]

Comment: I have changed my answer.  Let me know if it meets your needs.

Comment: Your requirements look strange to me, I'm not sure I understand what your goal is. Are you trying to take your result object and convert them to a dictionary which map from property names to values? There are much more efficient ways to get this desired behavior. In fact, using the [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) can give this all to you for free if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve to translate the whole thing into a key-value pair list when you actually want a list of objects back. Your function as given can be reduced to:

```
public static object GetSalesDataBySaleOrderID(SaleOrder sale)
{
    return sale.saleOrderItem
               .Where(s => s != null)
               .Select(s => new { 
                                  Id = s.Id,
                                  Username = sale.User.GetSingleUserById(s.UserId).Name,
                                  Amount = s.Amount 
                                })
               .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Works great. Could you please advice how do i ignore all the null value? I tried this .Select(..).DefaultIfEmpty().Tolist() But it still cast error with object null error.

Comment: @belinq: You have to add a `Where` clause and filter on `!= null`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Changed answer, now that the OP's original error is resolved.

```
 public static object GetSalesDataBySaleOrderID(SaleOrder sale)
 {
     List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
     for (int i = 0; i < sale.saleOrderItem.Count(); i++)
     {
         Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>()
         {
            {"SaleId", sale.Id},
            {"UserName", sale.User.GetSingleUserById(sale.saleOrderItem[i].UserId).Name},
            {"Amount", sale.saleOrderItem[i].Amount},
         };
         list.Add(result);
     }
     return list.Select (d => new { Id=(int)d["SaleId"], Username  = d["UserName"], Amount = (Decimal) d["Amount"]});
 }
```

Really, you should probably refactor this method, and the one you are trying to replace/cache so that it returns a well-known object (not an anonymous type).  It could return `List<Sale>` or something.

Answer (score 1):

@agent-j is right, you have to store each dictionary; however, if you want a list of key value pairs instead, you can use:

```
list.AddRange(dicionary.ToList());
```

Which converts the dictionary to `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` form.  This would duplicate the user name and amount keys many times.  I think the dictionary approach is what you want, just throwing it out there in case.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var list = new List<SalesOrder>(dictionary.Values);
```

or if you have already a list created:

```
list.AddRange(dictionary.Values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it a list of [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).  You can use them in a similar fashion as you do anonymous objects except it is mutable or you can use them as a dictionary (interface).

```
var result = myDataContext.MyTable
    .Where(sale => /* my conditions */)
    .AsEnumerable() // use LINQ to objects at this point
    .Select(sale =>
    {
        dynamic exo = new ExpandoObject();
        exo.SaleId = sale.Id;
        exo.UserName = sale.User.GetSingleUserById(sale.saleOrderItem[i].UserId).Name;
        exo.Amount = sale.saleOrderItem[i].Amount;
        return exo as IDictionary<string, object>;
    });

IDictionary<string, object> first = result.First();
// access the properties as if it were a dictionary
int saleId = (int)first["SaleId"]; // get (and cast) the SaleId property
first["UserName"] = "Bob"; // set the UserName property

// cast it back to dynamic to access the properties as if it were an anonymous object
dynamic dfirst = first;
decimal amount = dfirst.Amount; // get the Amount property (no cast necessary)
dfirst.Amount = 3238132.12M // set the Amount property
```